# Apache acting strange on symlinks

Tags: apache-2.2, symbolic-link, symlink

I have a VPS with CentOS and I'm facing a very strange behavior by Apache webserver.
I started this server with 50GB of disk space and soon I ran out of space so I asked maintenance department and they added another 50GB as a new hard drive. So I created a new partition and mounted it in `/home/media` and I moved all my website media files to this place and at the end I created an SymLink like this:

```
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 apache apache    12 May 15 14:07 media -> /home/media/
```

Today, I ran out of disk space once more and they did added a new hard drive with 100GB capacity this time. I just wanted to do the same as I did for `/home/media/` but this time it's called `/data/media`.

```
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 apache pooya    12 Jun  9 22:43 media -> /data/media/
```

Now when I navigate to files in media folder in browser, I get `Forbidden 403` error.

I checked Apache's error log and it says: **Symbolic link not allowed or link target not accessible: /var/www/html/media**.

All the solutions for this error on Internet is to add `Options Indexes FollowSymLinks` or webserver facing access problems with symliked directory.

I have the `FollowSymLinks` in both apache config file and my root `.htaccess` file. All the files and folders and also their parents in `/data/media/` are chmodded to **777** and the chown of them is `apache:apache`.

What is wrong with my webserver?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should almost never need to have 777 permissions in your web tree.

You probably need to fix the SELinux permissions since /data/media isn't a standard location to store web files. You can quickly test this by temporarily disabling SELinux

```
setenforce 0
```

Run some tests and if the web files are now accessible SELinux is to blame. Reenable Linux

```
setenforce 1
```

then fix the problem

```
semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_content_t "/data/media(/.*)?"
```

followed by

```
restorecon -r -v /data/media
```

Now apache should be able to access the files.

---

The semanage utility is provided by the policycoreutils-python package so you can install it with

```
yum install policycoreutils-python
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did typed `setenforce 0` but now I'm getting error 500 and apache log file says: **Premature end of script headers**

Comment: @faridv: You have other problems too.

Comment: Line what? I just created a new partition, mounted it to `/data/` and then copied media folder from `/home` to here. What should I do? It's a production website and now I'm stuck in a bad situation!

Comment: When I type `ls -Z` in `/data/` folder I get `drwxrwxrwx. apache apache unconfined_u:object_r:file_t:s0  media`. I have no idea what does it mean. Can it help me finding the problem?

Comment: @faridv: You have 2 problems. The first **Symbolic link not allowed or link target not accessible: /var/www/html/media** appears to be caused by SELinux and I've provided an answer to that question. The second **Premature end of script headers** is an entirely different problem and it's resolution is much more difficult to diagnose remotely and is more likely an application/programming error.

Comment: ok, ok, ok. I gotta admit I've done anything that I could to make it work. I created an alias for `media` folder to see if the result is different from symlink and I think error 500 was because of my bad virtual-directory configuration. I removed this alias there's no more error 500.

Comment: Now after typing `setenforce 0` it seems to work and as you said it should be cause by SELinux. but your solution does not seems to work because os cannot understand `semanage` command!?

Comment: @faridv: You need to install semanage, it's in the policycoreutils-python package. See my update.

Comment: Can you please explain what's the use of this command? and is `chcon -Rv --type=httpd_sys_content_t /data/media` similar to your solution?

Comment: @faridv: https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/12/html/Security-Enhanced_Linux/sect-Security-Enhanced_Linux-Working_with_SELinux-SELinux_Contexts_Labeling_Files.html and https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/12/html/Security-Enhanced_Linux/sect-Security-Enhanced_Linux-SELinux_Contexts_Labeling_Files-Persistent_Changes_semanage_fcontext.html